# How do I fix "a debugging check in this application has failed" error?

Tags: c++, debugging

I've recently managed to install Code::Blocks and a MinGW compiler on a new computer.

I have an issue with a debugger on Code::Blocks. It literally won't let me create any project and give me an error message.

The error message goes as follows:

```
wxWidgets Debug Alert

A debugging check in this application has failed.

../../src/common/file.cpp(361): assert ""(pBuf != __null) && IsOpened()"" failed in Write()
```

Here's a picture of the whole thing: [error message]
[image: img]

If I press stop, then everything crashes.

If, however, I press Continue, I get this warning:

```
Warning

Couldn't save project C:\Users\40737\Documents\yy\yy.cbp

(Maybe the file is write-protected?)
```

Here's a picture: [warning message]
[image: img]

If I go ahead and click okay, the same error shows up again:

A picture, again: [error shows up again]
[image: img]

What is there to do?

Comment: Have you checked the obvious? That code blocks has permissions to write to the places you are asking it to write to?

Comment: During the installation process did anything unusual happen? Were you asked anything that you didn't understand?

Comment: In the absence of any other information, the only advice is to reinstall.

Comment: It seems you are trying to save the project in an area belonging to user 40737. Is that your user name? Are you running code blocks using that user name, or a different user name?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Any solution?

Comment: It doesn't start at all with administrator rights. Im getting this error during startup and exit. Not during creation of a new project

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is make sure you have selected the path that you want to save. If you haven't select the path you want to create, you can see the resulting filename is showing **Invalid path**.

[image]

So after you select the path you want to create then you set your project title. After that, the invalid path message will disapper.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating new project just make sure you select the folder you want to save your project to.

Answer (score 0):

Please, select the path while creating a new project. After this issue will be solved.

good day ..

Comment: What do you mean by selecting a path?

Answer (score 0):

i got this bug when i name a file with a very long name, so just in case someone have the same issue with me, try shorten your file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

delete the space in the project name. that´s all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try running codeblocks as administrator

Comment: That sounds like a very wild guess, and in general: running a normal piece of software as "root" is the very last thing you want to do. So please elaborate why you think this would fix the problem.

Comment: because if I run codeblocks as administrator that type of error doesnt occur.

Comment: Problem is: security permissions exist for a reason. As I said: running *any* application with admin privileges isn't good practice.

Comment: It doesn't start at all with administrator rights. Im getting this error during startup and exit. Not during creation of a new project